# Android App not listed as compatible with nexus 6

Tags: android

I published an android app but its listed as not compatible with nexus 6. my app manifest looks like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
      <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <!-- see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html -->
    **<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="400" />**
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:debuggable="false">
    <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />        
        <activity android:name="Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
```

I have read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html) article. My understanding is that providing xxxhdpi icon is recommended but not mandatory and certainly the only things the app store uses to filter out apps and decide compatibility is the app manifest so that cannot be the issue. I am not using any `<compatible-screens>` element in my manifest so that also cannot be an issue. **What is the problem then and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `<supports-screens>` section in manifest.

android:normalScreens="false" but Nexus 6 has NORMAL screen.

Nexus 6 screen = 730 x 410 dp. 
According http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

*Nexus 6 screen is less than large* and because of this it is **NORMAL**.

If you are using   for Nexus 6 do not forget include 
    
`xxxhdpi` application icon (according [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)).